# csquotes -- How to customize/change blockquote features -- indentation, fontsize, linewidth

Tags: quoting, csquotes

Quotation requirements can be very variable and I've not found a way to adapt the `csquotes` standard for my puropse. For a thesis/paper it is required to fulfill following blockquotation standards:

- **fontsize** 10pt (different from the normal fontsize)
- **indentation** 1cm (relative to normal text)
- **linewidth** 1.0 (normal text is 1.5 -- `\onehalfspacing` with the `setspace` package)
- inside the **quotation marks** (set by `csquotes`)
- use **italics** for the quotation

Since specific language settings are also required, it would be very facile if  the proposed solution would use the same ´csquotes´ package.

I've found

- [1] [How to change the fontsize of a csquotes' quotation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370022/how-to-change-the-fontsize-of-a-csquotes-quotation)
  and
- [2] [\blockquote customization](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452111/blockquote-customization)

While the first is setting the fontsize only relative to the nomrla font size, the second is almost not commented and so practically impossible to adapt for a novice like me.

Here you find a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}    

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{setspace}       
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage[autostyle,german=guillemets]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
    Here comes a blockquotation:

    \begin{displayquote}
        Dies ist ein Zitat das nichts sagt. Und wenn sie noch nicht gestorben sind dann denken sie daran für immer zu sein.
    \end{displayquote}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When you say "linewidth", do you mean "line spacing"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this covers your requirements.  I commented it so that hopefully it's easy to follow.

```
\makeatletter
%Take the original environment definition and change the leftmargin to 1cm
\renewenvironment*{displayquote}
  {\begingroup\setlength{\leftmargini}{1cm}\csq@getcargs{\csq@bdquote{}{}}}
  {\csq@edquote\endgroup}
\makeatother
%Hooks
%Use single spacing, set 10pt font, and begin beginning quotes

%%%Curly quotes version
%\renewcommand{\mkbegdispquote}
    %{\singlespacing\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\selectfont\setquotestyle{quote}\textooquote}%
%%%German guillemets version
\renewcommand{\mkbegdispquote}
    {\singlespacing\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\selectfont\textooquote}%
%%%German guillemets version plus italics
%\renewcommand{\mkbegdispquote}
    %{\singlespacing\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\selectfont\itshape\textooquote}%
\renewcommand{\mkenddispquote}{\textcoquote}
```

I could not find any way to change the indent size... so I searched `csquotes` for the `displayquote` definition.  I copied that and threw it between `\makeatletter...\makeatother` (because it contains the `@` character.  Then, I put `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`, so that the `\leftmargini` dimension change would only apply within `displayquote` environments.

Next, I renewed the two hook commands that are applicable to `displayquote`: `\mkbegdispquote` and `\mkenddispquote`.  Basically, you just put whatever changes you need here.  In this case, you wanted single space, font size of 10pt, quote style (if needed, see version 2), and quotes.  Then, you put the beginning quotes and the ending quotes.

Here is a complete version from your example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{setspace}       
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage[autostyle,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\makeatletter
%Take the original environment definition and change the leftmargin to 1cm
\renewenvironment*{displayquote}
  {\begingroup\setlength{\leftmargini}{1cm}\csq@getcargs{\csq@bdquote{}{}}}
  {\csq@edquote\endgroup}
\makeatother
%Hooks
%Use single spacing, set 10pt font, and beginning quotes
\renewcommand{\mkbegdispquote}
    {\singlespacing\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\selectfont\textooquote}
%End displayquote environment with ending quotes
\renewcommand{\mkenddispquote}{\textcoquote}


\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,}

\begin{document}
    Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation:

    \begin{displayquote}
        Dies ist ein Zitat das nichts sagt. Und wenn sie noch nicht gestorben sind dann denken sie daran für immer zu sein.  Dies ist ein Zitat das nichts sagt. Und wenn sie noch nicht gestorben sind dann denken sie daran für immer zu sein.  Dies ist ein Zitat das nichts sagt. Und wenn sie noch nicht gestorben sind dann denken sie daran für immer zu sein.
    \end{displayquote}

Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation:

\end{document}
```

[image: modified displayquote environment with German quotes]

And, if you want to change the quotes to be `“` and `”`, you can change the quote style:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{setspace}       
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage[autostyle,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\makeatletter
%Take the original environment definition and change the leftmargin to 1cm
\renewenvironment*{displayquote}
  {\begingroup\setlength{\leftmargini}{1cm}\csq@getcargs{\csq@bdquote{}{}}}
  {\csq@edquote\endgroup}
\makeatother
%Hooks
%Use single spacing, set 10pt font, set quote style curly quotes, and beginning quotes
\renewcommand{\mkbegdispquote}
    {\singlespacing\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\selectfont\setquotestyle{quote}\textooquote}
%End displayquote environment with ending quotes
\renewcommand{\mkenddispquote}{\textcoquote}


\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,}

\begin{document}
    Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation:

    \begin{displayquote}
        Dies ist ein Zitat das nichts sagt. Und wenn sie noch nicht gestorben sind dann denken sie daran für immer zu sein.  Dies ist ein Zitat das nichts sagt. Und wenn sie noch nicht gestorben sind dann denken sie daran für immer zu sein.  Dies ist ein Zitat das nichts sagt. Und wenn sie noch nicht gestorben sind dann denken sie daran für immer zu sein.
    \end{displayquote}

Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation:

\end{document}
```

[image: Modified displayquote environment with standard quotes]

And version with italics (and German-style quotes):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{setspace}       
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage[autostyle,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\makeatletter
%Take the original environment definition and change the leftmargin to 1cm
\renewenvironment*{displayquote}
  {\begingroup\setlength{\leftmargini}{1cm}\csq@getcargs{\csq@bdquote{}{}}}
  {\csq@edquote\endgroup}
\makeatother
%Hooks
%Use single spacing, set 10pt font, set italics, and beginning quotes
\renewcommand{\mkbegdispquote}
    {\singlespacing\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\selectfont\itshape\textooquote}%\setquotestyle{quote}
%End displayquote environment with ending quotes
\renewcommand{\mkenddispquote}{\textcoquote}


\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,}

\begin{document}
    Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation:

    \begin{displayquote}
        Dies ist ein Zitat das nichts sagt. Und wenn sie noch nicht gestorben sind dann denken sie daran für immer zu sein.  Dies ist ein Zitat das nichts sagt. Und wenn sie noch nicht gestorben sind dann denken sie daran für immer zu sein.  Dies ist ein Zitat das nichts sagt. Und wenn sie noch nicht gestorben sind dann denken sie daran für immer zu sein.
    \end{displayquote}

Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation Here comes a blockquotation:

\end{document}
```

[image: displayquote with italics]

Comment: Thank you! Great! Actually I didn't wanted to change the quotation symbols (*>> Text <<*). Where do I change the symbols? Because this could help others to customize the quotation to their needs (-: (I've tried to change `\textcoquote`, it didn't work.)

Comment: Ah, ok.  I wasn't clear about this requirement.  Actually, you only need to remove the quote style change command (i.e. `\setquotestyle{quote}`).  I'll update the answer to include both versions (for anyone interested in either version).

Comment: @alex Updated.  By the way, I noticed in your comment that you used italics.  Do you also want the quote to be italicized?

Comment: Thank you! Have a good new year (-:

Comment: Apropos italics. For making your answer more popular you could show how to setup italics. I would then adapt the question.

Comment: Please adapt the documentclass to *article*. It works for both and would be more general. Thank you.

Comment: @alex Updated document class and added an italics version.  Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! I've added the requirement in the question. Have a nice day (-:

Answer (score 1):

We can avoid some patching if we use [the method to customise `displayquote` shown in `csquotes.cfg`](https://github.com/josephwright/csquotes/blob/ad510ad33fea8dab7cd530e1d533b0724847396d/csquotes.cfg#L221-L227).

The idea is to first define a new environment based on `quote` that does most of what we want. Then we use our new environment instead of the standard `quote` with `\SetBlockEnvironment`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{setspace}       
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage[autostyle,german=guillemets]{csquotes}

\newenvironment*{innerquote}
  {\setlength{\leftmargini}{1cm}%
   \quote
   \singlespacing\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\selectfont\itshape}
  {\endquote}

\SetBlockEnvironment{innerquote}

\renewcommand{\mkbegdispquote}[2]{\textooquote}
\renewcommand{\mkenddispquote}[2]{\textcoquote#1#2}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{displayquote}
\lipsum[2]
\end{displayquote}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image: Display quote with 1cm left/right indent, quotation marks, smaller line spacing, smaller (10pt) font and in italics]

Note that technically `\mkbegdispquote` and `\mkenddispquote` are defined as taking two arguments.